# memory issue in nodejs app (Sailsjs)

Tags: node.js, sockets, websocket, sails.js, polling

We've a memory problem in a Nodejs application!
We used :

Sailsjs as a framework

Mongodb as a database

Redis as a in-memory database

Pm2 as a proccess manager

Also we use Sailsjs socket module for socket connections.

- we used pm2 cluster mode for run this application.
- nginx for load balancing and reverse proxy.

Typically we've 3000 socket connection.

And transport is webSocket and polling.
Some of our client apps are connected to socket server with polling and some of them with websocket.

What is our main problem?

After run the app with pm2 in cluster mode, at first each cluster uses 230 MB of memory and
after about 4 hours it rises to about 2GB, in fact after 4 hours each cluster uses 2 GB of memory and the performance and speed of the app are going down sharply!

We doubt to a memory leak and use heapsnapshots and analyzed it.

Change "var" to "let" in all variables!

And this is our global gc code in bootstrap file

```
setTimeout(function () {
if (global.gc) {
  global.gc()
}}, 4000);
```

But we still couldn't find the problem. :(

If you have a tool or solution to solve our problem, please tell us.

If you need more information , please mention in the comment and i'll edit the question.

Thanks.

Comment: Well I am no expert in performance bottlenecks but could you just check if you're printing way too many logs, which pm2 might not be liking?

Comment: Try using `heapdump` module. https://github.com/bnoordhuis/node-heapdump